# How to transfer types to an edit-form component?

Tags: typescript, prisma, next.js14

There is an edit-page, it gets data using prisma,as follow:

`app\dashboard\invoices\[id]\edit\page.tsx`

```
import Form from '@/app/ui/invoices/edit-form';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();



async function fetchInvoiceById(id: string) {
  const data = await prisma.invoice.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: id,
    },
    select: {
      id: true,
      customerId: true,
      amount: true,
      status: true,
    },
  });
  const invoice = {
    ...data,
    amount: data!.amount / 100,   // Convert amount from cents to dollars
  };

  return invoice;
}



async function fetchCustomers() {
  const customers = await prisma.customer.findMany({
    select: {
      id: true,
      name: true,
    },
    orderBy: {
      name: 'asc',
    },
  });
  return customers;
}



export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const id = params.id;

  const [invoice, customers] = await Promise.all([
    fetchInvoiceById(id),
    fetchCustomers(),
  ]);

  return (
    <main>
      <Form invoice={invoice} customers={customers} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

the infered return type of function `fetchInvoiceById(id)` is like this:
[image]

and the infered return type of function `fetchCustomers()` is like this:
[image]

And the `Form` component is like this:
it has some errors because the props `{invoice, customers}` has no types.
`/app/ui/invoices/edit-form`:
[image]

How to transfer the types into it from `app\dashboard\invoices\[id]\edit\page.tsx`?

Comment: I think the best way would be to create a separate interface, keep that interface in a separate file and use it in the EditInvoiceForm when defining props
If you don't want to create the interface you can use ReturnType to get the return type of your function and export that type and import it in the other component
(Not sure about the spelling/casing of ReturnType)